# IntelliJ IDEA Hide Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, scrollbar

Using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2017.2, I am unable to have the vertical scrollbars disappear, even though the system settings are set this way. The transparent scrollbars appear to be visible at all times.

In contrast the vertical scrollbar disappears when not scrolling.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA uses its own implementation of the scrollbars that is cross platform and doesn't reflect any system settings.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for the info. Is that a platform choice? I guess my question is why can't the IDE use the default OS scrollbars. Is there anyway to remove this override? I am already using a 13'' monitor and would like to have only the essentials on the screen.

Comment: Scrollbar is customized so that it can show error/warning stripe marks without taking additional screen space There is no any way you can hide it or change its appearance.

Comment: @CrazyCoder please convert your comment to an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA uses its own implementation of the scrollbars that is cross platform and doesn't reflect any system settings.

Scrollbar is customized so that it can show error/warning stripe marks without taking additional screen space There is no any way you can hide it or change its appearance.

See also the https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Scrollbars+FAQ.